# When to used static visibility?

Tags: php, object-oriented, static

I can't attain the primary used of Static Visibility. My question is why they used static method & properties in this code?

```
class PassHash {

    // blowfish
    private static $algo = '$2a';
    // cost parameter
    private static $cost = '$10';

    // mainly for internal use
    public static function unique_salt() {
        return substr(sha1(mt_rand()), 0, 22);
    }

    // this will be used to generate a hash
    public static function hash($password) {

        return crypt($password, self::$algo .
                self::$cost .
                '$' . self::unique_salt());
    }

    // this will be used to compare a password against a hash
    public static function check_password($hash, $password) {
        $full_salt = substr($hash, 0, 29);
        $new_hash = crypt($password, $full_salt);
        return ($hash == $new_hash);
    }

}
```

Comment: Related (and possible duplicates): [OO PHP static keyword, should I use it?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/179003/oo-php-static-keyword-should-i-use-it), [Using static in PHP](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/150888/).  Please also check out the [php + static](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/static-methods+php) tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask yourself if a given method requires any state that is specific to an object instance.  If it does not, `static` is appropriate, since the method is scoped to the class itself, not to the object instance.

`static` methods are essentially utility methods; they take parameters, and return a value; nothing more.

Consider

```
public static function check_password($hash, $password) {
    $full_salt = substr($hash, 0, 29);
    $new_hash = crypt($password, $full_salt);
    return ($hash == $new_hash);
}
```

Does it require any state that is specific to an object instance?  Is everything that it needs passed in as parameters?  Does it store any state?  Does it return an idempotent value?

Also, *do you want to be able to call it without requiring a class instance?*

If all of these things are true, `static` scoping is more appropriate than object scoping.

Comment: Hi Thanks I'm 70% enlighten by your answer. can you please specify what do you mean on "utility methods; they take parameters, and return a value". I think non-static function normally do this.

Comment: Yes, you can do that with non-static methods, but you need to new up an object instance to use them.  More info at http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: "Does method called rarely?" can you consider this as a basis?

Comment: How often you call a method isn't really a factor when determining whether or not it should be made `static`.